# Conditional Lighttpd configuration based on request headers

Tags: lighttpd

Is it possible to conditionally configure Lighttpd based on custom request headers?

It's possible to do so by IP address (and other variables):

```
$HTTP["remoteip"] ==  "0.0.0.0" {
    // Do something
}
```

Is there something similar for request headers, for example:

```
$HTTP["X-Some-Header"] ==  "Value" {
    // Do something
}
```

I don't think there is looking through documentation and searching Google, but perhaps somebody knows a way.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following more searching I'm pretty confident that this isn't possible.

For me the solution was to change my application.

Comment: situation may have changed since, see answer of @rkian

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with with Lighttpd from 1.4.6 onwards, see https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_configuration

In my case it looks something like:

```
$REQUEST_HEADER["Content-Type"] == "application/rdf+xml" { 
    url.redirect = ( "^/somewhere/(.*)$" => "/somewhere-else" ) 
}
```